# Python regex that match column with non-uniform space separation between any 2 column?

Tags: python, regex

[image]

I have a text file that contain some numerical line of data that I need to match. The data are put into column separate by some space. For example, consider the third line:

```
101     NUC-A       21.600 1  1.0200 1.3450  450.00  -66.03 0.9894  49.64 0.2681 0.4167
```

We see that 101 in column 1 and NUC-A in column 2 is separated by 5 spaces. However column 2 and column 3 between the words NUC-A and 21.600 is separated by 7 spaces.

All the line that need to be match are marked by the red downward arrow.

There are a total of 12 columns, how can I extract all of these line that contain 12 columns out ? I still cannot think of any good pattern in the case

Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want *"a regex that matches columns with non-uniform space separation"*, you want to split at `\s+`.

```
import re

with open('filename', encoding='utf8') as file:
    for line in file:
        fields = re.split(r'\s+', line)
        if len(fields) == 12:
            print(fields)
```

You can do the same thing without regex, by splitting at the space and filtering out any empty strings.

```
        fields = list(filter(None, line.split(' ')))
        if len(fields) == 12:
            print(fields)
```

Comment: Thank you this is really the right way of thinking to solve this problem !

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh If you're using this solution, please don't forget to tick the "accepted" check mark.